# Unexpected PHP error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

**INDEX.PHP**

```
$user = db::getInstance()->get('test', array('user_name', '=', 'rahul'));

if ($user->count()){
    echo 'NO user';
} else {
    echo 'Ok';
}
```

**DB.PHP**

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = False;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){

        $x =1;

        if(count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param ) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

private function action($action, $table, $where){            
    if(count($where==3)) {

        $opertors = array('=', '<', '>', '>=', '<=');                

        $field   = $where[0];
        $opertor = $where[1];
        $value   = $where[2];

        if(in_array($opertor, $opertors)){                    

            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$opertor} ?";                    

            if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                echo ' Go it';
                return $this ;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where){
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}

public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count(){
    return $this->_count;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\ooplr\index.php on line 10

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to dump $user to see what is in it

Comment: `var_dump($user)` gives...?

Comment: it is giving 'boolean false' .......

Comment: You should quote the column name as well.

Comment: "what am I missing here?" - definitely a proper question title

Comment: what column name dude ?

Comment: I am new her.... do not know how should ask....

Comment: It looks like you are writing a query builder. Make sure you escape everything carefully, or there may be SQL injection possibilities here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether your `db::getInstance()->get` successfully returned the object. The following line:

```
if ($user->count()){
```

fails because `$user` is not an object here. The code follows:

```
$user = db::getInstance()->get('test', array('user_name', '=', 'rahul'));
if( !$user ) {
  echo 'EVERYTHING GOES WRONG';
} else {
  // OK, PROCESSING
}
```

Comment: No friend.... This is not the problem here......

it works when I use db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE user_name = ?", array('rahul));

Comment: **Sometimes** this `get` might fail and you **have to** check what was returned **every time** before doing a subsequent call to `$user->count()`.

Comment: if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error())

the condition which is given if statement is going false....

Do not know how ?

Comment: Simply `if(! $user) { /* THERE IS AN ERROR */ }` just before you are trying to access `$user->count()`.

Comment: Sorry Friend... I am not getting you..... will you explain by another way ???? Please

Comment: Thanks bro....... Error has been removed but.... it is giving me 'EVERYTHING GOES WRONG' ???

Comment: What have I done wrong? have you get it   ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
if(count($where)==3){
              ^^
```

instead of

```
if(count($where==3)){
```